# How do I override the default css on yii2 in controller

Tags: php, yii2, yii2-basic-app

AppAsset comes with yii2 basic

```
class AppAsset extends AssetBundle
{
    public $basePath = '@webroot';
    public $baseUrl = '@web';
    public $css = [
        'css/site.css',
    ];
    public $js = [
    ];
    public $depends = [
        'yii\web\YiiAsset',
        'yii\bootstrap\BootstrapAsset',
    ];
}
```

My Main Controller

```
class MainController extends \yii\base\Controller {

    public function init()
    {
        parent::init();
    }

    public function beforeAction($action) { 
        if(Yii::$app->request->get('site')) {
            // remove css/site.css
            // add css/other.css
        }

        return parent::beforeAction($action);
    }

    public function actionErro()
    {
        return $this->render('erro');
    }    

}
```

I need to remove the **css/site.css** and add a new one in place, with another name, as in the above code!

Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

Simplest way is to create your own Asset having all the old AppAsset dependencies but using the custom css and register it instead of AppAsset.

Comment: How would I register an appset in Controller? 
I tried like this:

            `$cs = Yii::app()->clientScript;
            $cs->registerCssFile('/css/layout_01.css');`

But it did not work for me

Comment: You register Asset in the view, preferably in layout.

Answer (score 0):

You can just rewrite 
`

```
public $css = [
    'css/site.css',
];
```

to

```
public $css = [
     'css/other.css',
     'css/other_second.css',
];
```

(if there are more then one css you want to connect).
Same is for js files. And remove the beforeAction part.

Comment: I need to register on the controller's `beforeAction($action)` method.

Answer (score 0):

My Solution

```
public function beforeAction($action) { 
    if(Yii::$app->request->get('site')) {

        Yii::$app->assetManager->bundles = [
            'app\assets\AppAsset' => [
                'css' => ['css/layout-01.css'],
            ],
        ];
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```